# how to add script based on current scene and considering DontDestroyOnLoad?

Tags: unity, c#

How to add script based on current scene?
I try

```
GameObject car = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("InGame");

if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "TestDrive")
        {
            car.AddComponent<CarCtrl>();
        }
```

but nothing what I expected 
I want if I am on scene **TestDrive** there it attaches script **CarCtrl** to car
I am using also `DontDestroyOnLoad` (because I want to pass 3d model between two scenes CarSelect and TestDrive) but have issue because the script attach to previous scene also (this is **CarSelect**) but I want only to attach the script in scene **TestDrive**
I have the answer I should use level manager but I can't find way to start

CarCtrl in TestDrive scene

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using Rgn;

public class CarCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private BoxCollider bc;

    public float horizontalInput;
    public float verticalInput;

    public float steerAngle;

    public List<Transform> Wheels;

    [Header("input")]
    public float steerInput;

    public float turnSpeed = 10f;

    public float maxSteerAngle = 30f;
    public float engineForce = 20;

    public const int topSpeed = 300;

    private TextMeshProUGUI speedText;

    private float speed = 0.0f;

    public void GetInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    private void Steer()
    {
        var dt = Time.deltaTime;
        steerAngle = maxSteerAngle * horizontalInput * dt;
        var smoothedSteering = Mathf.Lerp(0.0f, steerAngle, 10);
        var turnForce = transform.up * turnSpeed * smoothedSteering;
       // Debug.Log(turnForce);


        Wheels[0].Rotate(transform.forward * -1, steerAngle);
        Wheels[1].Rotate(transform.forward * -1, steerAngle);

        rb.AddRelativeTorque(turnForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }

    private void Accelerate()
    {
        // speed in m/s
        speed = rb.velocity.magnitude;
        var force = transform.forward * -1 * engineForce * verticalInput;
        var speedKph = Car.MpsToKmh(speed);
        if (speedKph < topSpeed)
        {
            var speedtxt = speedKph.ToString();
            rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Acceleration);
            speedText = (TextMeshProUGUI) FindObjectOfType<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            speedText.text = $"speed: {speedtxt} kmh";

            rollWheels();
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetInput();

        Accelerate();

        Steer();
    }



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        //stop rotating
        Destroy(GetComponent<Turn>());


      //  AddWheels();



        var car = new Car("make", "model");
        print(Car.AckermannLeft(2, 2, 10));



        this.gameObject.transform.Translate(-30, 0, 0, Space.World);

       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        rb.useGravity = true;

    }

    private void rollWheels()
    {
        var angle = engineForce * verticalInput;
        foreach (var wheel in Wheels)
        {
            wheel.Rotate(Vector3.right, angle);
        }
    }



    private void AddWheels()
    {
        Transform fl = GameObject.Find("Wheel_FL").transform;


        Transform fr = GameObject.Find("Wheel_FR").transform;
        Transform rl = GameObject.Find("Wheel_RL").transform;
        Transform rr = GameObject.Find("Wheel_FL").transform;

        Wheels.Add(fl);
        Debug.Log(Wheels);

        Wheels.Add(fr);
        Wheels.Add(rl);
        Wheels.Add(rr);
    }





}
```

DontDestroyOnLoad

```
 using UnityEngine;

public class DontDestroyOnLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject car = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Turn>().gameObject;



        var camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");

        camera.transform.parent = car.transform;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

Scenes

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Scenes : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
    }

    public void ChangeToMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }

    public void ChangeToTracks()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Tracks");
    }

    public void ChangeToMakes()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Makes");
    }

    public void ChangeToModels()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Models");
    }

    public void ChangeToGarage()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Garage");
    }

    public void ChangeToCarSelect()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("CarSelect");
    }

    public void ChangeToTestDrive()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("TestDrive");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I know why this not working because I have attached script CarCtrl to prefab initially in inspector and I should disable script on CarSelect and enable on TestDrive and no issue with it
but disable in DontDestroyOnLoad in CarSelect

```
var carCtrl = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("InGame").GetComponent<CarCtrl>();
                carCtrl.enabled = false;
```

also make enabler of script in TestDrive

```
if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "TestDrive")
        {
            var carCtrl = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("InGame").GetComponent<CarCtrl>();
            carCtrl.enabled = true;

        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it worked for you.